# Не получается использовать memset_s

Tags: c, cmake

Вот такой код в main.c

```
    buf = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*BUF_SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STR_LEN);
        memset_s(buf[i], sizeof(char)*MAX_STR_LEN, 0, sizeof(char)*MAX_STR_LEN);
    }
```

QtCreator выдает ворнинг

```
main.c:75:9: Implicit declaration of function 'memset_s' is invalid in C99
```

Я прописал в main.c

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <string.h>
```

И в CmakeLists.txt

```
project(target_name  LANGUAGES C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(target_name  main.c)
set_property(TARGET target_name PROPERTY C_STANDARD 11)
```

При попытке собрать проект, я получаю ошибку

```
undefined reference to `memset_s'
```

Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Замненить на [memset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)?

Comment: Хотелось бы все-таки использовать memset_s.

Comment: Ну, если у вас ее нет, то можете написать сами (или взять готовые [сорсы](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/osfmk/kern/memset_s.c.auto.html) (только вместо `secure_memset()` там, вызывайте `memset()`))

Comment: Функции с суффиксом `_s` являются опциональным расширением, они не обязаны присутствовать в стандартной библиотеке. Если данное расширение поддерживается, то должен быть определён макрос `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`. Проверьте его наличие.